# Restrict random color generator function to generate specific color in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

I'm generating random colors using below function:

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

I want to restrict this to generate all colors expect "#A9A9A9" or all shades of grey (if possible).

Putting some if condition after generating color and calling function again doesn't seem to be efficient. Please suggest how should i do?

Comment: Just checking a list of blacklisted colors and calling the function again is the easiest, and you have to generate the color first to see if it's one you want or not anyway.

Comment: No, i think there should be some way like this: As all the values of RGB code's in shades of grey are same, so if all the red green and blue value of color is same then ignore otherwise include it. But this should be done while generating color itself  not checking after color has been generated.

Comment: Sure, you could write some function that only generates colors you want, but you won't be able to just use `Math.random` and have a small fast function that generates colors. Most likely, it will be slower and way more complicated than just running the function again if the color is blacklisted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would limit your overall color space a bit, but you could do something like this since you are trying to get rid of (true) grey, which only occurs when all three RGB values equal each other.

```
var letters1 = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var letters2 = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
var rand1, rand2, i, len = letters1.length;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len - i));
    rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len - i));
    color += letters1.splice(rand1,1) + letters2.splice(rand2,1);
}
```

Or it could be smarter to just use the HSL color space:

```
var color = 'hsl(' + Math.round(Math.random() * 359) + ',100%,50%)';
```

Then you could limit by the range of Hues you want things to take, and make sure S/L are set at reasonable places and you will only end up with colors, no grey, black or white. W3 schools has a pretty good [HSL explorer](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_hsl.asp) for accepted values. If it has to be RGB you could convert the HSL to RGB pretty easily, check out https://github.com/Qix-/color-convert.

As an example of how this could get more complex, this function generate only non green colors based on my interpretation of green stop/start hue.

```
randomNonGreenColor = function () {
    //skip green
    var ranges = [[0, 60], [180, 359]];

    //get max random
    var total = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i += 1) {
        total += ranges[i][1]-ranges[i][0] + 1;
    }

    //get random hue index
    var randomHue = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);

    //convert index to actual hue
    var pos = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i += 1) {
        pos = ranges[i][0];
        if (randomHue + pos <= ranges[i][1]) {
            randomHue += pos;
            break;
        } else {
            randomHue -= (ranges[i][1] - ranges[i][0] + 1);
        }
    }

    return 'hsl(' + randomHue + ',100%,50%)';
}
```